# Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu}=\Phi g_{\mu\nu}\implies \Phi = \frac1n R$

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, trace

Say we are in an $n$-dimensional pseudo-Riemannian manifold for which $$R_{\mu\nu}=\Phi g_{\mu\nu},$$
where $\Phi$ is a scalar field and $R_{\mu\nu}$ is the Ricci tensor, and $R=g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}$.

Then shouldn't I find that this gives us:
$$g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu} g_{\mu\nu} \Phi =\Phi$$
So that:
$$R=\Phi,$$
Why is it apparently the case that $\Phi = \frac1n R$? Is there somehow a sum from $1$ to $n$ given by $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}$ perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}=\delta^\mu_\mu=\dim M=n$. The Kronecker delta represents the identity matrix, which in $n$ dimensions has $n$ 1s in its diagonal, therefore its trace is $n$.

Comment: With this in mind, say I am in an $n$-manifold, and I consider$$\Gamma_{ab}^{\,\,\,i} \delta_{a}^i$$
Should I be getting 
$$\Gamma_{ab}^{\,\,\,a}$$ or $$n\Gamma_{ab}^{\,\,\,a}?$$

I've been using $\delta$ wrong in such a case in the past if it's the latter.

Comment: I imagine its still the former, since Einstein notation sums over the $i$.

and in the case of the question $g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}=\sum_{\mu,\nu = 1}^n \delta_\mu^\nu = \sum_{\mu =1}^n \delta_\mu^\mu = n$

Comment: @grE It is the former. The contraction with $\delta$ sums over the indices, but because $\delta$ is only nonzero when the two indices coincide (and then it's 1), it means the two indices get summed over "together" and you get $\Gamma^a_{ab}$.

If you contract a single $\delta$ with itself, you get $\delta^\mu_\mu=\delta^1_1+...+\delta^n_n$ where *each and every* term in this sum consists of $1$ s, so you get $n$.